# Returning Wrong Data in Classes

Tags: c++

I'm learning classes and doing well, until I try to print out my Tom Animal class.

It gives me an output of:

> is 1246009934 cms tall and 0 kgs in weight. 
>   Animal  destroyed

As opposed to my Fred Animal class which returns:

> Fred is 33 cms tall and 10 kgs in weight. Animal Fred destroyed

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class Animal {
private:
    int height;
    int weight;
    string name;

    static int numOfAnimals;

public:
    int getHeight(){ return height;}
    int getWeight(){ return weight;}
    string getName(){ return name;}
    void setHeight(int cm){ height = cm;}
    void setWeight(int kg){ weight = kg; }
    void setName(string animalName){name = animalName;}
    void setAll(int, int, string);

    Animal(int, int, string);

    ~Animal();

    Animal();

    static int getNumberofAnimals() {return numOfAnimals;}

    void toString();
};

int Animal::numOfAnimals = 0;

void Animal::setAll(int height, int weight, string name){
    this -> height = height;
    this -> weight = weight;
    this -> name = name;
    Animal::numOfAnimals++;
}

Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name) {
}

Animal::~Animal(){
    cout << "Animal " << this -> name << " destroyed" << endl;
}

Animal::Animal(){
    Animal::numOfAnimals++;
}

void Animal::toString(){
    cout << this -> name << " is " << this -> height << " cms tall and " << this -> weight << " kgs in weight" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Animal Fred;

    Fred.setHeight(33);
    Fred.setWeight(10);
    Fred.setName("Fred");

    cout << Fred.getName() << " is " << Fred.getHeight() << " cms tall and " << Fred.getWeight() << " kgs in weight." << endl;

    Animal Tom(36, 15, "Tom");
    cout << Tom.getName() << " is " << Tom.getHeight() << " cms tall and " << Tom.getWeight() << " kgs in weight." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please help me out.  Thanks

Comment: Presumably `Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name)` is supposed to *do something*. By the way, Fred and Tom are not classes, they are objects.

Comment: `Animal::toString` should return a `string` and you should use it in the `main` function to output `Fred` and `Tom`'s details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructors do nothing, class members for `Fred` and `Tom` are uninitialized.

Use these instead:

```
Animal::Animal() {
    SetAll(0, 0, "");
}

Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name) {
    SetAll(height, weight, name);
}
```

Comment: You also missed the default constructor (see the other answer).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: good point! but your solution increments `Animal::numOfAnimals` twice `;-)`

Comment: @chqrlie I changed my answer.  But your numOfAnimals is flawed.  See  the update to my answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: yes indeed. And the story goes on... `Animal::numOfAnimals` isn't decremented by the destructor, so it is not a count of currently living Animals, but merely a count of Animal creations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues:

1) For the default constructor, you failed to initialize your member variables of `Animal`.

```
Animal::Animal()
{
    Animal::numOfAnimals++;
}
```

This should be changed to give some sort of default values:

```
Animal::Animal()
{
    SetAll(0,0,"");
}
```

---

2) In your non-default constructor, you failed to initialize the members.

```
Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name) 
{
}
```

It should be changed to this:

```
Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name) 
{
   SetAll(height, weight, name);
}
```

---

3) Your code will fail to update the number of Animals in the case of copy construction:

```
Animal Fred;
Animal Fred2 = Fred;
cout << Animal::getNumberofAnimals();
```

You will see that the output is `1`, even though there are clearly 2 Animal objects that are created.

To fix this issue, you need to have a copy constructor:

```
Animal::Animal(const Animal& rhs)
{
   SetAll(rhs.height, rhs.width, rhs.name);
}
```